# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in if statement

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to label my data, and I want to label all my data 1 or -1.
I had this piece of code which used to work fine.

```
#iris-setosa
train_t = df.iloc[0:120, 4].values
validation_t = df.iloc[121: , 4].values

train_t1 = np.where(train_t == 'Iris-setosa', -1, 1)
validation_t1 = np.where(validation_t == 'Iris-setosa', -1, 1)
```

Then I have another set of data which their labels aren't strings,
so I changed the code to this:

```
#iris-setosa
train_t = df.iloc[0:120, 4].values
validation_t = df.iloc[121: , 4].values

classNum = 20
train_t1 = np.where(train_t == classNum, -1, 1)
validation_t1 = np.where(validation_t == classNum, -1, 1)
```

and it doesn't label my data properly, instead it labels them all 0!

Then I tried to write the code with an `if` instead of `np.where` like this:

```
#iris-setosa
train_t = df.iloc[0:120, 4].values
validation_t = df.iloc[121: , 4].values

classNum = 20
for i in range (1000):
if (train_t[i] == classNum):
    train_t[i] = 1
else:
    train_t[i] = -1
if (validation_t[i] == classNum):
    validation_t[i] = 1
else:
    validation_t[i] = -1
```

and I get this error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
Update: apparently this error is gone for no reason, and instead all my data is labeled -1 instead which is not my desired result.

Comment: What is `classNum` in the dataset?

Comment: the label of the data set it changes from 1 to 36 and i want to consider data labeled 20 +1 and the rest -1

Comment: Are you using the right axis?

Comment: the axis was my problem Colin:) thank u

Comment: cool, I've added an answer so you can accept!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your train_t or your validation_t gets an int value assigned at some point.

the error

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

occurs when you use an int like a list

e.g.

```
x = 5
x[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably selecting the wrong axis, based on the fact that it's the same as it was when you were using `'Iris-setosa'`. Changing the axis should fix your problem.